# Trigger event right after Owl Carousel is loaded

Tags: jquery, owl-carousel

I would like to know how do I run a function right after Owl Carousel is loaded. I read through their callback functions but was not able to see any such callback action which you can call right after Owl Carousel is loaded fully.

If any body can help. Thanks is advance.

Comment: Which version of Owl Carousel are you using? What do you mean by 'fully loaded'?

Comment: I am using v1.3.2 and by fully loaded I mean when owl carousel is loaded and there is no further role of owl on that page.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
$('#owlcarousel').owlCarousel({
    items: 1,
    loop: true,
    autoplay: `true,`
    dots: false,
    nav: false,
    onInitialized: function() {
            //.... do some thing like
      alert("owl.carousel ready initialized") ;
      console.log("owl.carousel ready initialized") ;
    }
})
```